# Will I break code when returning a copy instead of a const reference

Tags: c++

A framework I need to work with defines a simple mutex class that can store the mutex owner's name as an aid in debugging:

```
class mutex
{
public:
    explicit mutex(const std::string& mutex_owner = "");

    bool acquire() const;
    bool release() const;

    const std::string& get_name() const {return owner_name_;}

    // ...

private:
    std::string owner_name_;

    // ...
};
```

I have just changed a few algorithms making the mutex type a template parameter so that I can pass in this one for performance reasons, if locking isn't needed:

```
class non_mutex
{
public:
    explicit non_mutex(const std::string& mutex_owner = "")     {}

    bool acquire() const               {return true;}
    bool release() const               {return true;}

    std::string get_name() const {return "";}
};
```

Since this one does not store a name (there's no need to debug this), I changed the `get_name()` member function to return a `std::string`, rather than a `const std::string&`.

Now my question is: *Could this* (***silently***) *break anything?* The code compiles just fine, and seems to run fine, too, but there's few tests in this codebase, and this function is mostly only used if something goes amiss, rather than regularly.

What are the cases when this change could trigger runtime failures?

Note that this is a C++03 environment, but I'd be interested in C++11 answers, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one that returns by value could potentially throw a bad alloc, the reference one is no-throw. So this could be a problem.

Also, there is a potential for them to call different overloads and traits would specialize differently, but I wouldn't worry about this.

Comment: Allocation could indeed be a problem, if an unlikely one. Given that we do not yet have rvalue references here, what potential is there for calling different overloads? (I am worrying about exactly those kids of problems. This is a small device that's meant to run 24/7.)

Comment: You might get lucky: if your `std::string` has a small string optimization then I think `std::non_mutex::get_name()` should be nothrow on your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are no longer returning a constant. You are returning a temporary.

Theoretically this could allow the user to misuse the return value? Perhaps?

Btw. I would solve the issue this way:

```
static std::string empty_string;
const std::string& get_name() const { return empty_string; }
```

Comment: note that this has different thread safety requirements as multiple mutexes will return the same name object reference.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Does that matter for constant objects?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: probably `empty_string` should be a constant object then ;-p. But I think you're right, as long as nobody modifies `empty_string` there shouldn't be any particular threading issues.

Comment: No offense meant, but this is incredibly vague. Three of the first four sentences just rehash what I already said in my question, the fourth hints that there might be something, where I wanted to know _what_ there could be. Thanks for the hint re resolving a problem, but the reason I came here to ask is exactly because I wanted to know whether this is necessary.

Comment: @sbi Well, that's why we have both the upvote and downvote buttons :-)

Answer (score 1):

For silent breakages, one difference is the lifetime of the object returned /  referred to by the return. For example, consider the following code:

```
const string &stupid_user(const string &s) { return s; }

const string &name = stupid_user(mtx.get_name());
mtx.acquire();
std::cout << name;
```

Now, if `mtx` has type `mutex` then this prints the name of the mutex's current owner after the `acquire`. If `mtx` has type `non_mutex` then it has undefined behavior (the const reference *does not* extend the life of the temporary in this case). Undefined behavior obviously allows that it *might* pass your tests.

With a less stupid user:

```
const string &name = mtx.get_name();
mtx.acquire();
std::cout << name;
```

Now the behavior with `mutex` is that it prints the new owner, with `non_mutex` it prints the old owner. Maybe your tests catch that and maybe they don't, but if the calling code assumed one and you supply a type for which it is the other, then you have silently broken the calling code.

Or how about:

```
auto &&name = mtx.get_name();
mtx.acquire();
std::cout << name;
```

I think this behaves the same as the non-stupid user, but I'm not sure.

If you (or future visitors to this question) are interested in noisy breakages then it depends how you defined the allowed expressions for use of your Mutex concept (which you're hoping the two classes you present both satisfy).

For example if the expression `&mtx.get_name()` is allowed, then `non_mutex` does not satisfy the requirements of the concept.

If you didn't allow that expression, then perhaps `non_mutex` does satisfy the requirements -- look closely at what expressions are allowed that involve calls to `get_name`. If all you required is that its return value is "convertible to `string`" or some such, then you're fine.

If you didn't define the requirements on the template parameter in terms of allowed expressions, but instead did so in terms of what member function signatures and return types it has then (a) you made a mistake, that's not how template-based compile-time polymorphism is supposed to work and (b) `non_mutex` doesn't have the same member function signatures and return types.

Comment: When I wrote _"silently"_, I meant that it doesn't cause any compile errors, as I am not worried about those. Code relying on the return value being a reference can be fixed when compilation fails. I am worried about code that compiles, but might fail at runtime. As such, this "silently" might even refer to spectacular errors. (BTW, I didn't ask how to fix code that relies on the result being a reference, I asked what kind of code this could be. `+1` from me for the one example of that you gave.

Comment: P.S.: As I have (belatedly) written in the question, there's no C++11 compiler for that platform, so we can't benefit from `auto`.

Comment: Maybe I'm just having a mental lapse, but wouldn't both examples (on the end of your answer) fail for `non_mutex`? I mean, getting a reference (bet it `const` or r-value) to a temporary doesn't extended the temporary life-time. So this should result in undefined behaviour not printing old user.

Comment: @sbi: my three code snippets aren't intended to be corrections of each other, they're supposed to be three similar examples of code whose defined behavior is different according to the type of `mtx`. Since you're not using a C++11 compiler, you can be reasonably confident that the last one doesn't appear in your code base, but either of the first two might :-)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: "getting a reference to a temporary doesn't extended the temporary life-time" -- yes it does, if you bind a reference to a temporary. 12.2/5 in C++03.

Comment: @SteveJessop But doesn't this fall into the exception of: _A temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) persists until the function exits._

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: correct. Since it doesn't fall into that special case (or any of the other special cases), it's covered by the general case, "The temporary to which the reference is
bound ... persists for the lifetime of the reference except as specified below". See http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: @SteveJessop Never mind, I seem to be misunderstanding the "binding".

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: This isn't a temporary bound to a returned value in a function return statement. This is a temporary that happens to *be* a return-value, bound to a reference variable. The exception you quoted is talking about code like `const string &foo() { return string("foo"); }`, it's saying that the temporary `string("foo")`, which is bound to the returned value in a return statement, persists only until the function returns and not for the full lifetime of the reference return value (which would be the end of the full-expression containing the call to `foo`). So `std::cout << foo()` is UB.

Comment: @SteveJessop So `cout << foo();` is UB, but `auto& v=foo(); cout << v;` isn't.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: those are both UB. About the only thing that is defined behavior is `(void)foo();`. The extension to the lifetime of the temporary is just long enough to allow the function to return, but you can't use the returned reference because it's dangling. Basically, you get extended lifetime when you bind a temporary *directly* to a reference, but when you bind a temporary to a reference and then initialize another reference using that first reference, you don't get the longer of the two extensions!

Comment: @SteveJessop Oh, right. It finally clicked in :-D Dammit, this C/C++ hybrid code base is really screwing with my brain. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, I understood what error you were pointing at. That's why I said `+1`. (Although I then forgot to... Sorry, I did now.) But your answer seems to fit better to my question now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel there is any problem with your changes. Both `get_name()` returns non-modifiable lvalue; attempt to modify them results in compiler error in C++03.

If you want to be pedantic, you can always make a choice based on SFINAE since you have templatized the code. With that you can completely remove `non_mutex::get_name()`.

Comment: `mutex::get_name` doesn't return an rvalue, it returns a non-modifiable lvalue.

Comment: I know how I can fix the code that exposes problems. I am just afraid that I might miss code that doesn't speak up at compile time, but fails at runtime.